# How to seperate keys and values from a json and store it in a array using useState hook in react

Tags: javascript, json, axios

```
function Graph() {
  const [tcases, setCases] = useState([]);
  const [recovered, setRecovered] = useState([]);
  const [deaths, setDeaths] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/all?lastdays=all")
      .then((res) => {
        setCases(Object.values(res.data.cases));
        setRecovered(Object.values(res.data.recovered)));
        setDeaths(Object.values(res.data.deaths)));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

I have tried the above code..it says cases,recovered and deaths are undefined

API used:[click here to see the api](https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/all?lastdays=all)
I want it like this ..Please help! :)

```
   tcases=[555,654,941...........]

   recovered=[17,18,26.........]

    deaths=[28,30,36...........]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What you have done seems fine to me , can you create a sandbox and share the link?

Comment: Here is the working solution . please check https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-morning-c11qv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Your solution works fine but can i use it as input for chart  ?

Comment: I think that was not the question , isnt it? Anyway ,what are you using for charts , material-ui or antd or something else?

Comment: It is.. i need the keys and values in an array so tht i can provide it as input for the charts..im using react apex charts. 
  https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-leftpad-ynn76?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you add the expected output to the question?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Thank you so much i got my problem solved... **JSON.stringify**  returns  a string..i wanted in array format so I had to use  **JSON.parse** method

Answer (score 0):

```
function Graph() {
  const [tcases, setCases] = useState([]);
  const [recovered, setRecovered] = useState([]);
  const [deaths, setDeaths] = useState([]);
  const [date, setDate] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/all?lastdays=all")
      .then(res => {
        setCases(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.values(res.data.cases))));
        setDeaths(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.values(res.data.deaths))));
        setRecovered(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.values(res.data.recovered))));
        
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

JSON.stringify returns a string..Inorder to store it in array format we will have to use JSON.parse which returns an object.

Comment: Just use this @sowmica , no need to use JSON.parse const series = [
    {
      name: "Cases",
      data: tcases
    },
    {
      name: "Recovered",
      data: recovered
    },
    {
      name: "Deaths",
      data: deaths
    }
  ];